# My vim keeps correcting indents of previous lines?

Tags: vim

When I edit HTML, I sometimes like to line-up attribute declarations like this:

```
<li class="dropdown"
    ui-route="..."
    ng-class="{active: $uiRoute}">
</li>
```

However, when I'm at the end of line 2 of my example and I enter a newline, vim seems to correct the indentation of line 2 to that of line 1. Here's a GIF of it happening:

[image: GIF of the problem]

I have `autoindent` on but disabling it doesn't seem to help.

Can I tell vim to stop doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you have set `filetype indent on` and the indent file: `xml.vim` was loaded.

If you rename the file to something like `foo.vim.txt` and `vim foo.vim.txt`, the indent would not be automatically adjusted when you pressed Enter.

More detailed info:

In you `$VIMRUNTIME/indent/xml.vim`, you can find:

```
setlocal indentkeys=o,O,*<Return>,<>>,<<>,/,{,}
```

that is, when you pressed `<Return>` in your `xml` file, the indent adjustment was triggered. read `:h indentkeys` for details.

If you don't want to let vim re-indent your line when you press `<enter>`, you can try `setlocal indentkeys -=*<Return>`. If you want it only to happen on certain filetype, i.e. `xml`, you can create autocommand.

Hope it helps.

#### P.S. I just found that your file might be `html` file, it is the same. You can check `$VIMRUNTIME/indent/html.vim`, you will see `<Enter>` is in the list too.